# Android Retrofit unexpected end of stream on Connection occur when navigate to new activity

Tags: android, null, retrofit, retrofit2, unexpected-token

I have home page of products where i load 10 products from retrofit api call request but when user click on the view more button app switch to new activity where same requests is done but 80 to 100 products there but the problem arises is first two time i got this exception and onfailure occur in retrofit that is unexpected end of stream on Connection{www.awintoo.com:80, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=www.awintoo.com/38.130.230.103:80 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1
but when i came directly into this activity it loads the data but when i switch through home activity view more button it doesnot work........

edited..
just now i find out the cause in onfailure method it show me this
java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=…

here is home activity retrofit call request

```
private void getTopRatedProducts() {
    final Call<ReviewsModelClass> productssCall=apiService.getProducts(10,0);
        productssCall.enqueue(new Callback<ReviewsModelClass>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ReviewsModelClass> call, Response<ReviewsModelClass> response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getProducts().size(); i++) {
                    productIds.add(response.body().getProducts().get(i).getProductId());
                    productTitles.add(response.body().getProducts().get(i).getProduct());
                    Log.d("finalyyy", "onResponse: "+"::size:: "
                            +response.body().getProducts().size()+response.body().getProducts().get(i).getProduct()+
                            response.body().getProducts().get(i).getProductId());
                    double price=Double.parseDouble(response.body().getProducts().get(i).getPrice());
                    double roundOff = Math.round(price * 100.0) / 100.0;
                    productPrices.add("$"+roundOff);
                    productImages.add(response.body().getProducts().get(i).getMainPair().getDetailed().getHttpImagePath());
                }
                addTopRatedProducts();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ReviewsModelClass> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Finallyyy", "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
}
```

here is intent in homepage activity

```
public void viewMoreProducts(View view) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,Cocoproductlistgrid4.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

this is new activity with same request through retrofit

```
        private void getTopRatedProducts() {
        final Call<ReviewsModelClass> productssCall=apiService.getProducts(60,0);
        productssCall.enqueue(new Callback<ReviewsModelClass>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ReviewsModelClass> call, Response<ReviewsModelClass> response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getProducts().size(); i++) {
                    productIds.add(response.body().getProducts().get(i).getProductId());
                    productTitles.add(response.body().getProducts().get(i).getProduct());
                    Log.d("checkingg", "onResponse: "+response.body().getProducts().get(i).getProductId());
//                    Log.d("finalyyy", "onResponse: "+"::size:: "
//                            +response.body().getProducts().size()+response.body().getProducts().get(i).getProduct()+
//                            response.body().getProducts().get(i).getProductId());
                    double price=Double.parseDouble(response.body().getProducts().get(i).getPrice());
                    double roundOff = Math.round(price * 100.0) / 100.0;
                    productPrices.add("Price : $"+roundOff);
                    productImages.add(response.body().getProducts().get(i).getMainPair().getDetailed().getHttpImagePath());
                }
                addTopRatedProducts();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ReviewsModelClass> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("checkingg", "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Same problem also happen to me when i click on single product and switch to fragments view pager where i showed details of each product........ Kindly anyone help..plz

Comment: You should call `response.body()` only once

Comment: why that???what is the disadvantage of not calling this methods many times....by the way i solved the problem elsewhere in retrofit object creation

Comment: Try it out, assign it to a variable, and same for `getProducts()` ;)